# In android, how to access file in assets or raw in c++ via url?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-assets

- I want to use the url of the files in assets or raw in C++ (JNI).
- However, I don't know how to obtain the url of these files, since I cann't use `getAssets().open()` in C++ code.

Comment: Who told you that there was an url?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to load a C++ file from a URL and load it in android

but it's illegal and google play doesn't let apps load codes dynamically in the google play store

1. first you should create a new android-ndk project with the same package name
2. then run

   ```
   ./ndk build
   ```
3. in the intermediate folder you will get .so files which are compiled files from c++
4. put files for x86, x64 , arm64, x86_64, or other ABIs files in your main project or serve it in the cloud server
5. you can download it in phone storage
6. add "lib" before SO file name and add the .so extension

   ```
   EXAMPLE -> libexample. so
   ```
7. simply call

   ```
   static {
       System.load("PATH_TO_THE_FILE/libfile.so");
   }
   ```

or call loading from ndk with

```
dlopen("PATH_TO_THE_FILE/libfile.so")
```